# Charging issue with Asus S200E

Tags: laptop, battery, asus-laptop, charging, charger

I have an [Asus S200E series laptop](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS_VivoBook_S200E/specifications/) that runs Windows 8 and I'm having trouble charging it. The Laptop will only charge when it's off (orange indicator turns on), and this also is not consistent, sometimes I need to plug and unplug the charging cable multiple times in order for it to resume charging. If I turn it on while charging it will stop immediately. I've already tried changing the charger but that didn't fix the problem.

I have had the laptop for about a year and this issue started about 2-3 weeks ago. Is there a way to pinpoint the exact cause of the problem? is it hardware issue or software?

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: you described my exact problem!

Answer (score 0):

[Download an Ubuntu ISO file](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
[Verify the download was corruption free](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0)
Use the free Open Source [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) app to [write it to a USB Flash Drive](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0)
Boot from that Flash Drive
Test as you did above to see if results replicate.
If they do, it's hardware.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :), i'll try that and see if it solves the problem.